# convert excel vba Function to c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, visual-studio

I have the vba excel function convert my string text to hash.

```
Private Function HashString(inputText As String, Optional secretKey = "") As String
    Dim asc As Object
    Dim enc As Object
    Dim textToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    
    If secretKey = "" Then secretKey = inputText
    
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")

    textToHash = asc.GetBytes_4(inputText)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.GetBytes_4(secretKey)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey

    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((textToHash))
    HashString = EncodeBase64(bytes)
End Function
Private Function EncodeBase64(arrData() As Byte) As String
    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objNode As Object
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.Text
End Function
```

I want to use this function on other C# platforms to have the same algorithm output,
How to convert this method to C#?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your VBA code is using the .NET framework. C# uses the .NET framework. So your objects, methods, and properties are exactly the same and call the same code.

Comment: Unfortunately converting code from one language to another is considered out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you wrote this code, then you should understand the algorithm. From that algorithm you can then re-program into whichever language like C#.

Comment: i copy this code from web and test its worked so i need to use this in c#, I'm not a professional programmer.

Comment: How do you know that the code above does what you need it to do? What are you trying to achieve? What's the URL for where you got the code?

Comment: https://luiswu.wordpress.com/2016/06/08/hash-string-with-hmac-sha1-base64-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Tim Williams.
[Answer link](https://luiswu.wordpress.com/2016/06/08/hash-string-with-hmac-sha1-base64-in-c/)